# How do I access a property from a class method?

Tags: php

I need to create an instance of a class in my constructor, and then access it in the rest of my methods.

I have tried `init` function and `constructor` both, but no luck (as I am new in OOP concepts)

```
private $client;

// first I tried this
public function __construct(){
    $this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
}

// then I tried this
public function init(){
    $this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    // I also tried that
    // $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
}

/**
 * [xyz description]
 * @return [void]
 */
public function xyz(){

    // I need to use that client variable here

}
```

How can I use `$client` in my `xyz` method and other methods in the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it via `$this->client`, like you do in the constructor:

```
class Foo
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    }

    public function xyz()
    {
        $this->client->get('...');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was just missing `$this` and using `$client`